# Did Democrats protest lack of vote on a bill that ACLU argued as "undermining civil liberties"?

Tags: politics, guns

> There were the selfie-happy Democrats singing "We Shall Overcome" while **demanding passage of a bill that those right-wing nutjobs over at the American Civil Liberties Union have "strongly" argued would undermine civil liberties**.
>   (*source: ["Democrats: We Will Overcome the Constitution"@Reason.com](http://reason.com/archives/2016/06/24/democrats-we-will-overcome-the-constitut)*)

For those who don't know the context, a group of Democratic lawmakers in US House of Representatives [staged a "sit-in"](http://thefederalist.com/2016/06/23/the-symbolic-self-liquidation-of-the-democratic-sit-in/), to protest failure to pass gun control bills as a response to Orlando, FL shooting.

The "demanding passage" part of a claim is pretty obvious (if not 100% accurate, the bills weren't even brought to vote because they failed in the Senate), but the assertion that **ACLU<sup>[1]</sup> argued that the proposed bills that failed to pass "would undermine civil liberties"** is something unexpected.

<sub>[1] the "right-wing nightejobs" part of the claim is meant as an irony.. ACLU (American Civil Liberties Union) is generally viewed to be more liberal than conservative and doesn't exactly have a reputation of strong Second Amendment support, compared to many other liberties</sub>

Comment: I haven't downvoted this question, but it feels a little like publicising a talking point rather than asking a useful question.

Comment: @andrew there is no usefulness requirement for questions on this site.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm When people want to publicize a talking point, they usually simultaneously self-answer and accept their own answer. http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/27704/is-this-tweet-about-classes-one-month-after-the-hiroshima-bombing-and-the-2011/27705#27705

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The ACLU did characterize the proposed bills as undermining civil liberties because they would use the no-fly list, a list that the [ACLU has long argued violates due process](https://www.aclu.org/know-your-rights/what-do-if-you-think-youre-no-fly-list), to restrict access to guns (or in the case of Feinstein's bill, another yet-to-be-created list that they also characterize as overly broad).

[Here is their position statement on these bills](https://www.aclu.org/blog/washington-markup/use-error-prone-and-unfair-watchlists-not-way-regulate-guns-america). This paragraph summarizes their problem with one of the bills:

> The ACLU strongly urges you to vote against the Cornyn Amendment because it uses the error-prone and unfair watchlist as a predicate for a proceeding to deny a firearms permit.   The Cornyn Amendment establishes the watchlist system as the basis for the government to seek a court order denying a gun permit.

They posted almost the same argument on [December 7, 2015](https://www.aclu.org/blog/speak-freely/until-no-fly-list-fixed-it-shouldnt-be-used-restrict-peoples-freedoms).

They had similar due process concerns with Feinstein's bill.